# How do I save the dictionary with new name every time when my code runs?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to save the dictionary with new name , every time whenever my code runs .

**Code**:

```
   import json
   dictionary = {'happy':1,'sad':2,'angry':3}
   count = 0
   with open('/home/hamza/Desktop/time_duration_file'+str(count)+'.json','w') as data:
   file = json.dump(dictionary,data)
   count+=1
```

Above code is overwriting the dictionary whenever my code runs . I want to save the dictionary every time with a new name ,whenever my code runs.

**Expected output:**

```
Code Runs (1)
Code Runs (2)
     .
     .
```

**Ouput should be:**

```
 time_duration_file1.json
 time_duration_file2.json
         .
         .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `time` for doing this. Try this:

```
import json
import time

dictionary = {'happy':1,'sad':2,'angry':3}

with open('/home/hamza/Desktop/time_duration_file'+str(time.time())+'.json','w') as data:
        file = json.dump(dictionary,data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not doing anything to actually count the number of files already created; you're just setting `count` to zero.

Try something like

```
import glob

count = len(glob.glob('/home/hamza/Desktop/time_duration_file*.json'))

# ...
```

Comment: please send me complete code , after embedding with your particular line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import random

with open('/home/hamza/Desktop/time_duration_file'+str(random.randint(1, 10000))+'.json','w') as data:
    file = json.dump(dictionary,data)
```

This will create a completely different file name everytime you run your script.

And if you want to save continuous you can try this :

```
import os 

with open('/home/hamza/Desktop/time_duration_file'+str(len(os.listdir("/home/hamza/Desktop")))+'.json','w') as data:
    file = json.dump(dictionary,data)
```

Comment: this is giving error , no such file or directory time_duration_file/2983.json

Comment: Can you please explain which is not working? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Rabi before shouting on helper, provide complete error message, you are getting and ask to help with that!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the value stored in `count` is not going to be preserved. In other words, each time your code runs, the value of count is reset to 0. As Daniel has mentioned, you could solve this by counting the number of json files already in the directory and then adding one.

This would look something like:

```
import glob
import json

count = len(glob.glob('time_duration_file*.json'))
dictionary = {'happy':1,'sad':2,'angry':3}
with open('time_duration_file'+str(count+1)+'.json','w') as data:
   file = json.dump(dictionary,data)
```